# What are the different ways to say "Chapter" in Chinese?

Tags: vocabulary

So, I've been trying to figure out the proper way to say "chapter" for a long time in Chinese. 
Is this something that depends on a case by case basis? (i.e. a chapter in a novel would be different in a textbook.) Or is there one word that cover all of the different uses? (Or are there multiple?).

Comment: Textbooks usually use 单元, which mean unit but is equivalent to the English 'chapter'. 章 is more likely to be used in modern novels for chapter. Ancient materials would be more likely to use 回.

Answer (score 6):

There are a quite few ways to denote a chapter in Chinese. Some of the most commonly seen are:

章, 卷, 回, 篇.

If you wish, you can easily find examples of their usages here: "www.shuku.net". For your convenience, here are some links.

章: 
http://www.shuku.net:8080/novels/classic/zhongyong.html

卷:
http://www.shuku.net:8080/novels/history/csdsgz/sgz.html

Because I need at least 10 reputation points to post more than 2 links, I cannot link examples of others.

Answer (score 4):

There are many examples of chapter usage on [Jukuu](http://jukuu.com/search.php?q=chapter) here are two common usages I've seen (referring to the chapter by content or number).

Referring to a chapter in a book:

> {This chapter} focuses on personas and their goals. Other models are considered briefly at  the end of the chapter.
>
> {本章} 重点讨论人物角色及其目标，结尾处将简要谈谈其他模型。

Usage with a number:

> For more on scrollbars, see {Chapter 21}.
> 关于滚动条的更多信息参见 {第21章}。

More samples from Simplified-Chinese English Dictionary
[image: SCE-Dictionary Samples]

### From CC-Dict:

> zhāng
>
> 章
>
> chapter; section; clause; movement; seal; badge; regulation; order
>
> 章
>
> zhāng jié
>
> 章节
> chapter; section
>
> 章節
>
> juàn
>
> 卷
>
> scroll; book; volume; chapter; examination paper; classifier for books, paintings: volume, scroll
>
> 卷

Other usages may exist but they get further away from the more common usage of the word chapter.

Answer (score 1):

There are several possibilities, from a dictionary:

chapter   ['tʃæptə]
n.
1.
(书、论文或其他著作的)章，节，回

Answer (score 0):

cover all of the different uses : 章